# Can I have more than one while(!feof) loop in a program?

Tags: php

If I'm trying to display a table (which I've accomplished with a while loop) but also display a count underneath it. Do I add another while loop? Or a seperate for loop? How would I do that? I need to count the number of performances (Ive got that working) but it wont tally the number of performances in Asheville. How do I target that variable by itself?

```
>   <?php       print ("<h1>Upcoming Performances in 2015</h1>");       print
> ("<table border =\"1\">");        print("<tr><th align =
> \"left\">Date</th><th align = \"left\">Venue</th><th align =
> \"left\">City</th><th align = \"right\">Ticket Price</th></tr>");
> 
>       $count = 0;         $ashevilleCount = 0;        $eventFile =
> fopen("performances.txt", "r");       $schedule = fgets($eventFile);
> 
>       
>               while(!feof($eventFile))        {           list($date, $venue, $city, $ticketPrice) =          explode(":", $schedule);
>                       print("<tr><td>$date</td>");            print("<td>$venue</td>");           print("<td>$city</td>");            print("<td>$ticketPrice</td>");
>                       $schedule = fgets($eventFile);
>                   }
>       
>                           for($count = 1; $count <= 5; $count = $count + 1)       {           $total = fgets($eventFile);             $count = $count + $total;
>                   }
>               if ($city == Asheville)
>               $ashevilleCount = $ashevilleCount + $count;
>       
>   
>       
>       
>       
>                   fclose($eventFile);
>               print ("</table>");
> 
>       print ( "<p class=\"alert\">Lower cost venues are marked with
> *</p>");      print ("<p>NUMBER OF PERFORMANCES: $count</p>");        print ("<p>NUMBER OF PERFORMANCES IN ASHEVILLE: $ashevilleCount</p>");
>       
>       
>               
> 
> ?>
```

Comment: You're missing brackets `{}` around your if/elseif chunks

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at your `if` statements.

```
if($condition === true){
    //executes if $condition is true
} elseif($condition === 1) {
    //executes if $condition is 1
} elseif($condition === 2 || $condition === 3){
    //executes if $condition is 2 OR condition is 3
} elseif($condition === 4 && $otherCondition !== "foo"){
    //executes if $condition is 4 AND $otherCondition is NOT "foo"
} else {
    //executes if no other statements are true
}
```

---

This piece of code:

```
 elseif
 ($charType == human or dwarf and $goldSpent <= 10)
 $supplyTokens = $_POST['supplyTokens'] + 10;
```

Needs to look like:

```
 } elseif( ( $charType=="human" || $charType=="dwarf" ) && $goldSpent <= 10) {
      $supplyTokens = $_POST['supplyTokens'] + 10;
 }
```

---

Remember:

- `||` = "or"
- `&&` = "and"
- `test` != `"test"` - make sure your strings are enclosed in quotation marks

See:

- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code cleaned up. What was done:

- Changed all the `print()` commands to concatenated `echo`s.
- Fixed the conditionals

  - You don't need to check for `$goldSpent <= 10` in your `elseif`s as you have already checked that by *not* being in `$goldSpent > 10`
  - I personally prefer `||` and `&&` as opposed to `or` and `and`
- Added curly brackets `{}`

Thing to consider:

- What would happen if any of those `$_POST` values are empty??

```php
<?php

$charName = $_POST['charName'];
$charType = $_POST['charType'];
$healthTokens = $_POST['healthTokens'];
$expTokens = $_POST['expTokens'];
$supplyTokens = $_POST['supplyTokens'];

$goldSpent = $healthTokens / 10 + $expTokens / 2 + $supplyTokens / 25;

if ($goldSpent > 10) {
    echo "<h1>HEY THERE, $charName!</h1>" .
         "<p>YOU SPENT MORE GOLD THAN YOU HAVE!</p>" .
         "<p>GO BACK AND TRY THAT AGAIN - YOU HAVE 10 GOLD PIECES..</p>";
} elseif ($charType == 'elf') {
    $healthTokens = $_POST['healthTokens'] + 5;
} elseif ($charType == 'wizard') {
    $expTokens = $_POST['expTokens'] + 2;
} elseif ($charType == 'human' || $charType == 'dwarf') {
    $supplyTokens = $_POST['supplyTokens'] + 10;
}

$totalGold = 10;
$goldLeft = $totalGold - $goldSpent;

echo "<h1>You have created $charName the $charType!</h1>" .
     "<p>$charName has <strong>$healthTokens</strong> health tokens," .
     "<strong>$expTokens</strong> experience tokens, and" .
     "<strong>$supplyTokens</strong> supply tokens.</p>" .
     "<p>You received some bonus tokens! :)</p>" .                         
     "<p>$charName has spent <strong>$goldSpent</strong> gold pieces, " .
     "and has <strong>$goldLeft</strong> gold pieces left.</p>";
```

Comment: When I try this I get errors all over the place. I'm in this class because its a requirement for my degree (in DESIGN) lol I have ZERO desire to program. I just don't understand it. And I have no idea what echo is... we've not discussed it. This is for chapter 8 which is Multiple Selection, Nesting, ANDs and ORS. So I'm pretty sure we have to use the structures that I had originally.

Comment: I forgot a `{` at the end. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Okay, nevermind... they were my fault... But it's still doing all the calculations even if the amount goes over 10... How do I get it to JUST display the error message?